# Windows Run Command No Longer Knows How to Open Folders in Certain Locations

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, start-menu, run-dialog

One day, my Run Command forgot how to open folders, but only certain folders.

Regular folders work fine:

[image: A regular folder works fine]

But special folders, like ones I access all the time as an engineer, such as `%appdata%` or `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp` will show a "How do you want to open this?" dialogue.

[image: Accessing user's folder doesn't work.]

USERNAME is where I would put my user name.  Don't worry.

[image: How do you want to open this file?]

In a File Explorer window, such paths seem to work just fine, including `%appdata%`.

[image: File explorer works fine]

(I have tried Googling this issue a few times, but unfortunately it leaps to "Start menu doesn't work" or "File Explorer stopped responding," which isn't at all what I'm seeking.  Google seems blind to the term "run," probably because its used in so many different ways.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Anything funny under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory` and `...\Folder`? (Try deleting those keys completely, only from HKCU of course, not from HKLM.)

Comment: Just to confirm, this isn't the case, you are not literally trying to open `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp` correct?  Since that folder would not exist on your machine.  If you navigate to %appdata% within File Explorer does it take you to the correct folder location?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.

Comment: Does registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder` contain an item named `AppUserModelID` whose value is `Microsoft.Windows.Explorer`?

Comment: @Ramhound, I updated my post answering your questions.

Comment: @harrymc, it does contain that key and value.

Comment: Please try creating a new user.  Does the behavior exhibit itself on that new user?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @user1686, Directory has no values.  Just two empty folders, Background and shellex.  Folder also has no values.  Just a single empty folder, shellex.

Comment: Run [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Let us know the results.